# Category URL to use same string as Post URL Permalink

Tags: posts, permalinks, pages, urls, options

I want to set up my site to have the following permalink structure:

```
/learn/%category%/%postname%
```

So in the permalinks section of wordpress, I set that as the custom structure. The issue is, when I click on a category page it's just:

```
 /%category%/
```

(it's ends up being a `/category/subcategory/` url).

So I tried setting the category base on the permalinks setting page also to `/learn/`, but then I get a 404 when I go to a post's page.

[image: My Structure]
How do I make it so both category pages and post pages use the `/learn/` to start the url?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the rewrite rules overlap, WordPress is trying to find a category name that matches the post slug.

A possible solution is to do a little manual query parsing, check if the request contains `category_name` and is a term first, and reset query vars to post `name` if nothing is found:

```
function wpd_fix_category_requests( $request ){
    if( array_key_exists( 'category_name' , $request )
        && ! get_term_by( 'slug', basename( $request['category_name'] ), 'category' ) ){
            $request['name'] = basename( $request['category_name'] );
            unset( $request['category_name'] );
    }
    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'wpd_fix_category_requests' );
```

This is pretty basic, and maybe not reliable enough for primetime. Obviously you can't have a post slug that matches a category name. Also, singular post pagination won't work, and I assume attachment URLs will be broken as well.

You could fix all of those things following this method, if you were so inclined. Look at what `$request` contains for each type of page view, maybe with a different permalink structure so you can see what it looks like in a successful case. You just need to convert the query vars from one kind of request to the other, and WordPress will carry on loading the correct object.